# Struggling with batch processing in Azure Table Storage locally

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I have these batches that contain more than 100 entities that I'm trying to split to send in my local Azure storage account (Azurite):

```py
def save_results_in_database(self, operations, table_name):
        table = self.table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name)
        if table_name is None:
            raise Exception(f"Table {table_name} does not exist !")
        try:
            table.submit_transaction(operations)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(
                f"Error while saving results in database for table {table_name}"
            )

if 0 < len(results) < 100:
        helpers.save_results_in_database(results, action)
    else:
        # if the number of results is greater than 100, we need to split them in batches of 50
        # and save them in batches
        batch_size = 50
        for i in range(0, len(results), batch_size):
            batch = results[i : i + batch_size]
            helpers.save_results_in_database(batch, action)
            sleep(10)
```

And for some reason somes batches pass and some don't. For example if I have 107 entities to push, the first 50 pass, the second 50 doesn't and the remaining 7 pass.

I tried putting some sleep but I'm not sure it actually helps.
Here's the error message:

```
Error while saving results in database for table <table name>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/data/tables/_table_client.py", line 734, in submit_transaction
return self._batch_send(self.table_name, *batched_requests.requests, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/data/tables/_base_client.py", line 334, in _batch_send
    raise decoded
azure.data.tables._error.TableTransactionError: 2:An error occurred while processing this request.
ErrorCode:InvalidInput
Content: {"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"2:An error occurred while processing this request.\nRequestId:994b1eca-1109-4ff9-aa56-0dc73ae97a18\nTime:2023-04-06T13:08:29.278Z"}}}
```

Am I missing something? Because I'm fairly certain that the input is valid schema-wise.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong, one of the RowKeys had a "/" in it, breaking the operation.
Make sure to check your data!